# Android Studio not communicating with adb GLIBC .... not found error

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, adb, centos6.5

Android studio was communicating with adb normally. Right after updating platform-tools to version 23, android studio stopped communicating with adb.

It displays the message:

> Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to
>   detect adb version, adb output:
>   /data/programs/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb: /lib64/libc.so.6:
>   version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by
>   /data/programs/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb)
>   /data/programs/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb: /lib64/libc.so.6:
>   version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by
>   /data/programs/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb)

I have Centos 6.5 (final) Kernel 
Linux 2.6.32.431.el6.x86_64
Gnome 2.28.2

Comment: Same here! why did they compile it with a high version :( I think the only solution to this problem is to upgrade the distribution because one can't simply upgrade GLIBC on the dist or the easiest way is to rollback to a previous version of the platform tools.

Comment: Issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197074

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the only solution to this problem is to upgrade the distribution because one can't simply upgrade GLIBC on the dist

A temporary workaround is to rollback to a previous version of the platform tools.

The version introduced this is **platform-tools_r23.1.0**.
The last working version is **platform-tools_r23.0.1**.

You can download the last working version from 
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip

Just extract it and replace the platform-tools folder inside your sdk folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked but still a temporary solution. Hopefully, android team will find a actual fix for this problem.

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried replacing the platform-tools downloaded from your link and replaced it inside the android sdk folder. Can you please help?

Comment: @smiley That used to work back then, I'm sorry I upgraded my system and can't help with that. Now they require GNU C Library (glibc) 2.19 or later https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Requirements

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary solution:
I have a copy of the previous version of platform-tools folder. I replaced the new folder with the older one. back to normal.

But I still wish someone finds a solution to make platform-tools v23 works on Centos machine.